# Adding a voice output to the python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, mnist, voice, handwriting-recognition

i want to improve this project, i shared the link of it down below.
In the link that i shared i want to improve the project where i want to add a voice output when the digit gets recognised for example in the screnshots shown there are the numbers 1, 7 after the numbers gets recognised by the program i want the voice output to say 1 or 7 or something this way.

https://github.com/rkshiyaniya/Multiple-Handwritten-Digit-Recognition

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You tried **pyttsx3** or **gTTS**? The first one is not so grate but is doing the job. If your AI recognize the letter, number or the word you can print it as a debug I assume. If you can do that than you can use that data on "text to speech"